# how to set gridlayout from js from a string of layout defined

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to set a grid layout as below in xml

```
layout: `<GridLayout row="0" rows="*, 2*, *">
              <GridLayout width="57%" row="0" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
                <Label class="lobster-regular carousel-item-head" text="Welcome to Payments App" textWrap="true"></Label>
              </GridLayout>
              <GridLayout class="carousel-item-circle" row="1" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
                <Label class="fa carousel-item-icon" text="&#xf19c;" textWrap="true"></Label>
              </GridLayout>
              <GridLayout width="49%" row="2" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
                <Label class="opensans-regular carousel-item-desc" text="Let's see a quick overview of our features." textWrap="true"></Label>
              </GridLayout>
            </GridLayout>
            `,
```

so i created a scroll view from js and tried to add content to it as below. but its giving stackerror.

also i found  that https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=sRSad7&v=162 here they implemented same thing. but difficult to understand.

but when i tried the similar thing i'm not able to do so, here is my project link. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=GbN2TT

```
const myScroll = new ScrollView();
  myScroll.orientation = "vertical";

  console.log(homeViewModel.layout);
  myScroll.content = homeViewModel.layout;
```

please give me in detail suggestion and answer or alternative to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UI Builder](https://docs.nativescript.org/5-4/api-reference/modules/_ui_builder_)

```
const layout = `<GridLayout row="0" rows="*, 2*, *">
              <GridLayout width="57%" row="0" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
                <Label class="lobster-regular carousel-item-head" text="Welcome to Payments App" textWrap="true"></Label>
              </GridLayout>
              <GridLayout class="carousel-item-circle" row="1" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
                <Label class="fa carousel-item-icon" text="&#xf19c;" textWrap="true"></Label>
              </GridLayout>
              <GridLayout width="49%" row="2" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
                <Label class="opensans-regular carousel-item-desc" text="Let's see a quick overview of our features." textWrap="true"></Label>
              </GridLayout>
            </GridLayout>
            `;

const builder = require("tns-core-modules/ui/builder");
const gridLayout = builder.parse(layout);
myScroll.content = gridLayout;
```

Comment: The `myScroll` element is never part of the UI, you are suppose to add it to UI first? `page.content = myScroll;` - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=GbN2TT&v=4